# after adding "additional where clause" in QueryDatabaseTableRecord, process can't produce flowfiles

Tags: oracle, select, where-clause, apache-nifi, to-date

I need to get data from ***Oracle*** to ***PostgreSQL*** by ***Nifi***.

I successfully get data by using
***QueryDatabaseTableRecord*** & ***PutDataBaseRecord***.

I want to query the data which is after a certain date and time such as ***`2021-12-12 15:00:00`***.

> So I added an ***`"Additional WHERE clause"`*** as
>
> ***`trndate >= TO_DATE('2021-12-12 15:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`***
>
> in ***QueryDatabaseTableRecord***

However, after this step, ***QueryDatabaseTableRecord*** can not produce flowfiles although it deals with some tasks.

There are no special issues in ***`nifi-app.log`*** and ***`nifi-bootstrap.log`***, and my ***Nifi***'s version is *1.15*.

How should I use where clause then ?

*The image to illustrate my case* :

[image]

Comment: There's no problem except for putting the ending parentheses`)` after `trndate >= TO_DATE('2021-12-12 15:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` if `trndate` column's data type is **date**.

Comment: I surely put this in nifi additional where clause : 
trndate >= TO_DATE('2021-12-12 15:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

But it still does not work to produce flowfile.

Comment: Interesting, it works fine on my test case

Comment: Check state (View state) on a processor QueryDatabaseTableRecord